# Event to return null in order to specify a storage option

Tags: c#, event-handling, dicom, in-memory

I am trying to receive a DICOM file and save it in memory. The libary I'm using ([RZDCX](http://rzdcx.roniza.com/index.html)) allows for this by setting `app.EnableInMemoryStorageSCP` true:

```
DCXAPP app = new DCXAPP();
```

---

```
acc.OnStoreSetup += new IDCXACCEvents_OnStoreSetupEventHandler(OnStoreSetupEventHandler);
```

---

```
private void OnStoreSetupEventHandler(ref string filename)
{
     app.EnableInMemoryStorageSCP = true;
}
```

This is when I run into trouble the documentation ([Found Here](http://rzdcx.roniza.com/group___storage_s_c_p.html)) says that EnableInMemoryStorageSCP must be true and the event `acc.OnStoreSetup` return a null or zero length value. However if I change the event it seems no matter the return type the `OnStoreEventHandler(ref string filename)` has the wrong return type.

Is there a way to avoid this error and return a null value?

P.S. I thought it might mean setting `filename` null or to the zero length, but if null it continues saving as regular and for a zero length string it gets stuck trying to store the file.

Answer (score 0):

A a.
The right way to do it is:

```
// When your program starts
DCXAPP app = new DCXAPP();
app.EnableInMemoryStorageSCP = true;

//...

private void OnStoreSetupEventHandler(ref string filename)
{
     filename = null;
}

// ..

// and inside OnStoreDoneEventHandler(string filename, bool status ref bool accept)
{
   DCXOBJ obj = accepter.TakeStoredObject();
// ... do stuff with it
}
```